# Better process to scrape huge amount of data simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, curl

I am building a web app that has this process.

1) User registers

2) After user registers, i am running a [queuing process](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) that scrapes 60k+ worth of customer data. These data came from a 3rd party API and I use curl in doing this.

3) After I scrape these data, I store it in the database.

4) These scraped data from the 3rd party api has a pagination, so what I do is that I checked the response of the API if it has another page (`nextPageUrl`) and if it has that response, I `curl` again then get all the customer data and store it again. This continues until there's no `nextPageUrl` from the api response.

```
//this is a pseudo code

RegisterUser(user);
CallThirdPartyAPI()

function RegisterUser(user){
 insert_in_users_table(user)
}

function CallThirdPartyAPI($url=null){
    $customers = get_all_customers();
    for($customer as $cust){
      store_in_customers_table();
      if($cust->response_has_next_page_url)
         CallThirdayPartyAPI($cust->next_page_url);
      else
         return false;
 }
}
```

Now as you can see, this is ok if I only have 1 user at a time registering in my web app. But as I have a 100+ users registering in my web app, this is becoming a problem because scraping of data takes 20-30 minutes to be finished and I am running the job queue of only having 2 jobs at a time. So basically the 2 jobs needs to be done in order for the other jobs to be executed.

Now, i am looking for a better solution that would enhance and make the system efficient.

Your suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

**PS:**

I am running job queuing through supervisor

I have a read replica implemented in my database. I write in the master db while read on the replica to lessen cpu usage of my db.

Comment: Is the queuing process not sufficient? Once another worker is available it starts the next one?

Comment: `100+ users registering in my web app` at this point your system should by scaled for many other reasons, too.

Comment: You can create a new job instance for every nextPage. But in this case you should limit count of active jobs

Comment: Most API's have a rate-limit, and if you reach it, your entire app will suffer. If you are interfacing with something like facebook, brandwatch,google or pretty much anything else, you should be able to increase how many results you see per page, so you dont need to do 'nextpageurl' thing.

Comment: @James as i said queuing takes 20-30 minutes. so when the last user who registers, say 100th registered user. He should wait for the 1-99 queue to be finished before his scrape to be executed.

Comment: Which part is the biggest bottleneck? Is it the time to generate all those requests (if I understand correctly you make as many API requests per user as there are pages?). Is it processing data? Is it possible to get all results in one request? Or if memory is an issue, as few as possible?

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower Sorry, does this mean users need that scrape before their account is ready? If their account takes 20-30 mins to be ready possibly look at placing that queue runner on a separate server with more runners/processes. If you can't do that and can't find a solution, tell the user the account takes time to generate and they will receive and email when it is ready.

Comment: Does every user has it own access token to the api endpoint(scraping service)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sql database? Have you consider using no sql's such as MongoDB. I had a similar issue: using curl to get huge amount of data. With MongoDB it is more efficient and faster as it uses no sql and you can store those data as json/array,however you want.
You can also Use MongoDB for your API and sql database for others.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into something like RabbitMQ ( https://www.rabbitmq.com/ ) and use the following package: https://github.com/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq

You can set up it to where you can have a few workers which will handle gathering your data in the background. I think this may be a more scalable solution as well.